# Integrate PowerBI in windows 8 App

Tags: windows-8.1

I am developing a windows 8 app . The app should render the PowerBI charts and reports hosted in a sharepoint site. I need to know whether there is any way to do this. I need to know if it is possible to view the charts made by PowerBI inside a windows 8 app.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the question. If you'd like to do this with Power View in Office 365, there's a way to do it.  You can read about it here:

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powerbi/archive/2014/12/11/embed-power-view-interactive-reports-in-your-blogs-and-websites.aspx
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shishirs/archive/2014/02/13/analyzing-search-trends-using-powerbi.aspx

This works for embedding a canned report that is saved somewhere in Office 365.  This probably won't work well for your Windows 8 application.

Embedding in applications is something we're looking to add in Power BI, but it's not available right now.

Please submit an idea at the link below to help us prioritize and keep you updated when we add this to the service.
http://support.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi

Appreciate your using Power BI.

Lukasz P.

Power BI Team, Microsoft

If you'd like to stay up to date with the Power BI developer story updates you can register (http://solutions.powerbi.com/appsuggestion.html) or follow our blog (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powerbidev/)